# Process id of the parent's parent - Linux

Tags: c++, linux, process, fork

I have three processes in a chain: P1 -> P2 -> P3. I would like to be able to print out the id of all three from within the child(P3) process.

So, my question is how do I get the pid of a grand parent(P1) of the grand child(P3) with getppid() and such?

Or am i going to have to resort to storing the pid of each in their own variables for later use(not desireable)?

Thank you for any assistance you can give me. Also, just because, here is my code thus far:

```
//test_wait.cpp
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  pid_t pid;            //process id
  const char *message;
  int n;
  int exit_code;
  std::stack<int> proc_stack;

  cout << "Fork program starting\n";
  proc_stack.push(getpid());
  pid = fork();
  switch ( pid ) {
  case -1:
    cout << "Fork failure!\n";
    return 1;
  case 0:
    pid = fork();
    switch ( pid ) {
    case -1:
      cout << "Fork Failure!\n";
      return 1;
    case 0:
      cout << "Grandchild PID: " << getpid() << endl;
      cout << "Parent PID: " << getppid() << endl;
      cout << "Grand Parent PID: " << proc_stack.top() << endl;
      exit_code = 9;
      break;
    default:
      exit_code = 0;
      break;
    }
  default:
    exit_code = 0;
    break;
  }

//waiting for child to finish
  if ( pid != 0 ) {             //parent
    int stat_val;
    pid_t child_pid;

    child_pid = wait ( &stat_val );     //wait for child
  }
  exit ( exit_code );
}
```

So, I ended up using a stack to store the information. As seen in the above code now.

Comment: Linux utils that can walk around the process tree basically read from `/proc` (like `pstree`).  There's no POSIXy-type API to get the parent's parent.

Comment: You should `cout << fflush`  before every `fork`

Comment: Neat, but unfortunately the process outputting the "1" outputs is not the youngest child process in the end. As this was a requirement I cannot choose yours as the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Joe 
So, from what I understand I would need to do some parsing of the system process tree to find the "P3" parent's parent?

Answer (score 1):

You need to print pid and ppid when in child `case 0:` refer this code.

```
  //test_wait.cpp
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  pid_t pid;            //process id
  const char *message;
  int n;
  int exit_code;

  cout << "fork program starting\n";
  pid = fork();
  switch ( pid ) {
  case -1:
    cout << "Fork failure!\n";
    return 1;
  case 0:
   cout << "Child1 finished: PID = " << getpid() << endl;
    cout << "Parent PID = " << getppid() << endl;
   pid = fork();
    switch ( pid ) {
    case -1:
      cout << "Fork Failure!\n";
      return 1;
    case 0:
    cout << "Child2 finished: PID = " << getpid() << endl;
    cout << "Parent PID = " << getppid() << endl;
      message = "This is the child\n";
      n = 5;
      exit_code = 9;
      break;
    default:
      message = "This is the parent\n";
      n = 3;
      exit_code = 0;
      break;
    }
  default:
    message = "This is the grand parent\n";
    n = 3;
    exit_code = 0;
    break;
  }
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
    cout << message;
    sleep ( 1 );
  }
//waiting for child to finish
  if ( pid != 0 ) {             //parent
    int stat_val;
    pid_t child_pid;

    child_pid = wait ( &stat_val );     //wait for child
  }
  exit ( exit_code );
}
```

Also you can get ppid from /proc

cat /proc/pid/stat
e.g. for PID #20467:

```
cat /proc/20467/stat
```

20467 (abc) S 20137 20467 20125 34818 20467 4202496 1930 5196 22 0 113 162 32 25 20 0 1 0 1701252 14548992 1606 4294967295 4194304 6492552 2076847264 2076842300 694388884 0 0 0 134889479 2151083916 0 0 17 0 0 0 221 0 0

The 20137 in the above (4th field) is the PPID.

Comment: Cool idea, but unfortunately the process outputting the "Child1 finished" and "parent PID" outputs is not the youngest child process in the end. As this was a requirement I cannot choose yours as the best answer. Thanks for your knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, will have to do some parsing. Thanks.